# I need a script file for checking (ping) 3 ip address are working or not

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, mail, ping

I need to create a script for checking (ping) 3 ip address are working or not.
using the crone tab and i do want to know how is it working.
I was used a script using a test file, but i need to get the alert message in my mail af any one ip address is down..
please help me anyone.
thanks in advance

i have used this script..

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $( cat $HOME/iplist.txt )
do
ping -q -c2 $i > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo $i "Pingable"
else
echo $i "Not Pingable"
fi
done
```

with the ip list.txt file.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while` loop with `read` to get each IP address and then use `ping`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r ip; do
    if ping -q -c2 "$ip" &>/dev/null; then
        echo "$ip is Pingable"
    else
        echo "$i Not Pingable"
    fi
done <"$HOME"/iplist.txt
```

Comment: I am getting the output as pingable.

Comment: but i need the output in my mail if one ip address check is failed.
what can i do for that...

Comment: @Sajinu: all you have to do to get email notification is: **1)** Install an MTA (e.g.`postfix`) on yr box. **2)** Configure it as send-only with an `smtp` server from yr favorite outside provider. **3)** Replace one line (`echo "$i not pingable" `) in heemayl's otherwise perfectly good answer with  `echo "$i not pingable" | mail -s "subject line" username@domain.com`.--- Installing, configuring and running an MTA (e.g. `postfix`) is outside the scope of yr question. There are numerous answers and tutorials for that on AU and on the web.